# How to diagnose if lubuntu system freezes due to low memory?

Tags: linux, memory

I have a laptop with 3 gigs RAM that freezes up consistently after about a week when running Lubuntu linux 14.04 in live USB mode (no hard drive). Another laptop that has 16 gigs RAM never freezes up.

I want to determine if the laptop freezes up due to not enough RAM, or if it's a hardware problem like bad memory.

How can I run diagnostics while it's still running to determine if it's about to run out of available RAM and freeze up?

Answer (score 2):

Any of these commands will show you amount of free memory:

```
free
top
htop
```

If you see that swap space is used that is the point when system becomes less responsive.

Comment: And if swap is being used and it freezes at that moment there are reasons to suspect the HDD or SSD instead of RAM. I would also suggest memry diagnostics like MemTest because how much memory is being used doesn't tell us about defects in it.